# Assign new object to parameter object in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

say i have a block like so:

```
Object someObject = nil;

block = ^(Object *obj){

    if(obj == nil)
        obj = [[Object alloc] init];
};

block(someObject); //someObject is still nil
block(someObject); //it will assign again, instead of not

NSLog(@"result: %@", someObject); //still nil
```

it seems as though you cant assign things to parameters in blocks this way, is there some way to do it? this block acts on different objects, and needs to assign it if the object is nil. in this state, some object is only assigned in the scope (so `obj` is assigned, but not `someObject`). ive tried using `__block` but i dont think thats what this is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to parameters, blocks act like functions. What you are doing here is similar to how NSErrors are being handled by Apple's API.

Try this:

```
Object * someObject = nil;

block = ^(Object **obj){

    if(obj != nil && *obj == nil)
        *obj = [[Object alloc] init];
};

block(&someObject); //someObject is still nil
block(&someObject); //it will assign again, instead of not

NSLog(@"result: %@", someObject);
```

Comment: ah bugger, this does work and is the answer, but you can only seem to use local variables anyway, if i have a variable defined in the header i cant `&variable` it :/ `passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write back`

Comment: The other way is to use a __block variable and not use it as a parameter at all as was suggested by few others. I don't think there is a way in between.

Comment: damn, well i was hoping to pass this block around to do some inits on objects + some other setup code, so the someObject is going to change depending where it is, so i cant use it as a local variable like that... oh well guess ill have to figure out some other way

Comment: @Fonix: You could try changing the parameter to `^(Object * __strong *obj)` to see if it works better for you

Answer (score 3):

You could also go for this approach:

```
__block Object someObject = nil;
block = ^(void)
{
  if(someObject == nil)
    someObject = [[Object alloc] init];
}
block();
```

Comment: for what i need to do, this wont work, since this block exists in many places, and the object wont come from the context the block is being executed

Answer (score 1):

For a sample - declare a typdef similar to this in your header or something:

```
typedef void (^ActionBlock)(NSArray **array);
```

and then use it like:

```
__block NSArray *array = nil;
NSLog(@"Before: %@",array);
ActionBlock block = ^(NSArray **array)
{
    if(*array == nil)
        *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
};
block(&array);
NSLog(@"After: %@",array);
```

outputs:

```
2013-04-05 21:05:23.153 TestingSuite[62813:c07] Before: (null)

2013-04-05 21:05:23.155 TestingSuite[62813:c07] After: (
)
```

hope this helps

Comment: i have tried that, but to no avail... maybe im missing something though

Comment: I will write a sample - gimme a sec